# Meta tag robots noodp

Tags: seo, google-search, meta-robots

Does Google still crawl a page when this is used?

```html
<meta name="robots" content="noodp"/>
```

And when should this be used?

Our robots.txt is set to index all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google will still crawl the page, but if there is information about your page on [dmoz](http://www.dmoz.org), Google wont display that information on it's search result page.

> One source Google uses to generate snippets is the Open Directory
>   Project. You can direct us not to use this as a source by adding a
>   meta tag to your pages.
>
> To prevent all search engines (that support the meta tag) from using
>   this information for the page's description, use the following:
>
> `<meta name="robots" content="NOODP">`
>
> To specifically prevent Google
>   from using this information for a page's description, use the
>   following:
>
> `<meta name="googlebot" content="NOODP">`
>
> If you use the robots meta tag for other directives, you can combine those. For instance:
>
> `<meta name="googlebot" content="NOODP, nofollow">`

[Source](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=en)

Comment: Do I still need to put INDEX combined with NOODP?